# VB Copying Values from XML into Strings using XMLDocument

Tags: xml, vb.net, ssis, xmldocument

Before I ask this question please be aware I have very limited knowledge of VB (.net or other) and have achieved what I have so far by many internet searches.

I am currently making a call to an API (successfully) that returns a basic XML. I currently load this XML response into a XMLDocument and within that the XML looks as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<UniqueCouponResponse xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://api.website.co.uk/">
    <LogId>ffffffff-dddd-9999-ffff-2faf432ea2bd</LogId> 
    <StatusId>0</StatusId> 
    <EntryId>99999999</EntryId> 
    <UserId>88888888</UserId> 
    <Coupon>AAAACouponCodeBBBB</Coupon> 
    <ExpiryDate>2017-09-26 23:59:59</ExpiryDate> 
</UniqueCouponResponse>
```

The above example was copied from the XML viewer whilst debugging the code in Visual Studio. 
Note that the UniqueCouponResponse has no parent element and only one of these elements will be returned each time the API call is made.

What I need is to extract the values from the elements, such as the LogID and ExpiryDate, into dedicated string fields but I am experiencing issues with empty nodes and the For Each is jumping out immediately with none of the strings being assigned.

The code I have been using is as follows:

```
    Dim XMLDoc As New XmlDocument()
    XMLDoc.LoadXml(responseFromServer)

    Dim nodes As XmlNodeList = XMLDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/UniqueCouponResponse")
    Dim strLogID As String = "", strEntryId As String = "", strCoupon As String = "", strExpiryDate As String = ""

    For Each node As XmlNode In nodes
        strLogID = node.SelectSingleNode("LogId").InnerText
        strEntryId = node.SelectSingleNode("EntryId").InnerText
        strCoupon = node.SelectSingleNode("Coupon").InnerText
        strExpiryDate = node.SelectSingleNode("ExpiryDate").InnerText
    Next
```

As I say I am not a VB. developer in any way shape or form and so would appreciate some help or feedback as to what I am doing wrong and how I can extract these values.

Thanks in advance.

---

Edit: I have been pointed in the right direction with regards to using namespace and have the following VB code that works for me.

```
    Dim XMLDoc As New XmlDocument()
    XMLDoc.LoadXml(responseFromServer)


    Dim xmlns As New XmlNamespaceManager(XMLDoc.NameTable)
    xmlns.AddNamespace("dc", "http://api.website.co.uk/")

    Dim nodes As XmlNodeList = XMLDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/dc:UniqueCouponResponse", xmlns)

    For Each node As XmlNode In nodes
        Dim strLogID = node.SelectSingleNode("dc:LogId", xmlns).InnerText
        Dim strEntryId = node.SelectSingleNode("EntryId", xmlns).InnerText
        Dim strCoupon = node.SelectSingleNode("Coupon", xmlns).InnerText
        Dim strExpiryDate = node.SelectSingleNode("ExpiryDate", xmlns).InnerText
    Next
```

Comment: I commend you for getting as far as you did.  The problem you are running into is that you aren't specifying the element namespaces in the XPaths (the strings passed into `SelectNodes` and `SelectSingleNode`).  This is a common problem, even for experienced .NET developers.  Anyway, the linked question has an answer that demonstrates how to fully qualify the elements with the namespace.  If you still have trouble, let us know.

Comment: Thank you, I will check into this and let you know how I get on.

Comment: I have now manged to generate the code I needed to capture these values by using the name space. Thanks for pointing me in a better direction @StevenDoggart